# Oracle GoldenGate Java Adapter lost data when transactionCommit() failed

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-golden-gate

I'm currently developing a custom handler to deliver Oracle change logs.

When some errors occurred, normally, I can throw RuntimeException or return Status.ABEND. Then OGG would log the error and stop the process.

The following code works well when operationAdded() failed (i.e., Extract process will report abend, and when the Extract restart after the errors, the operations of the whole failed transaction would be resent to the handler).

```
@Override
public Status operationAdded(DsEvent e, DsTransaction tx,
        DsOperation dsOperation) {
    Status status = super.operationAdded(e, tx, dsOperation);
    ...
    //throw new RuntimeException("op add runtime error");
    return status;
}
```

However, when error occurred in the transactionCommit() function, OGG doesn't work as expected. Neither throw RuntimeException nor return Status.ABEND can stop the Extract. OGG just keep working like nothing happened. (Codes below)

```
@Override
public Status transactionCommit(DsEvent e, DsTransaction tx) {
    super.transactionCommit(e, tx);
    Status status = sendEvents();
    handlerProperties.totalTxns++;
    //throw new RuntimeException("tx ci runtime error");
    return Status.ABEND;
}
```

I tried to kill and restart the Extract process. The failed transaction were not resend to the handler. It seems that all the failed transaction data were lost !

Following are the logs of return Status.ABEND in transactionCommit():

```
...
DEBUG [main] (AbstractHandler.java:509) - Event: handler=ggdatahub, transactionCommit ( Commit transaction ) DsTransaction [ops=1, buffered=1, state=BEGIN, start=2015-08-21 20:04:25.842275, end=2015-08-21 20:04:25.842275]
WARN [main] (DsEventManager.java:231) - Error sending event to handler: status=ABEND, event=Commit transaction, handler=ggdatahub
Exception in thread "main" com.goldengate.atg.util.GGException: Unable to commit transaction, STATUS=ABEND
    at com.goldengate.atg.datasource.UserExitDataSource.commitActiveTransaction(UserExitDataSource.java:1392)
    at com.goldengate.atg.datasource.UserExitDataSource.commitTx(UserExitDataSource.java:1326)
Error occured in javawriter.c[752]:
***********************************************************************
Exception received committing transaction: com.goldengate.atg.util.GGException: Unable to commit transaction, STATUS=ABEND

DEBUG [main] (UserExitDataSource.java:504) - (JNI) C-user-exit checkpoint event
DEBUG [main] (UserExitDataSource.java:1364) - UserExitDataSource.CommitActiveTransaction: Same transaction committed more than once (possibly due to commit-on-checkpoint).
DEBUG [main] (UserExitDataSource.java:516) - UserExitDataSource.userExitCheckpoint: incrementing the flush counter
DEBUG [main] (PendingOpGroup.java:315) - now ready to checkpoint? false (was ready? false): {pendingOps=1, groupSize=0, timer=0:00:00.000 [total = 0 ms ]}
DEBUG [main] (UserExitDataSource.java:504) - (JNI) C-user-exit checkpoint event
DEBUG [main] (UserExitDataSource.java:1364) - UserExitDataSource.CommitActiveTransaction: Same transaction committed more than once (possibly due to commit-on-checkpoint).
DEBUG [main] (UserExitDataSource.java:516) - UserExitDataSource.userExitCheckpoint: incrementing the flush counter
DEBUG [pool-1-thread-1] (AbstractDataSource.java:737) -  [2] getStatusReport: Mon Aug 24 10:51:14 CST 2015
DEBUG [Thread-1] (UserExitDataSource.java:1601) - UserExitDataSource closing, #1 of class=UserExitDataSource
DEBUG [main] (PendingOpGroup.java:315) - now ready to checkpoint? false (was ready? false): {pendingOps=3, groupSize=0, timer=0:00:00.000 [total = 0 ms ]}
DEBUG [Thread-1] (UserExitDataSource.java:1608) - Shutting down data source; attempting a final checkpoint.
INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (AbstractDataSource.java:730) - Memory at Status : Max: 455.00 MB, Total: 60.50 MB, Free: 27.54 MB, Used: 32.96 MB
DEBUG [pool-1-thread-1] (UserExitDataSource.java:1637) - time spent checkpointing: 0:00:00.000 [total = 0 ms ]
DEBUG [Thread-1] (UserExitDataSource.java:1668) - doCheckpoint() called
INFO [pool-1-thread-1] (AbstractDataSource.java:980) - Status report: Mon Aug 24 10:51:14 CST 2015
*************************************************
Status Report for UserExit
*************************************************

Total elapsed time:        2 days 14:47:06.139 [total = 226026 sec = 3767 min = 62 hr ]   => Total time since first event
Event processing time:  0:00:12.692 [total = 12 sec ]   => Time spent sending msgs (max: 4795 ms)
Metadata process time:  0:00:02.159 [total = 2 sec ]   => Time spent receiving metadata (1 tables, 3 columns)

Operations Received/Sent:  3 / 3
 Rate (overall):         0 op/s    (peak: 0 op/s)
      (per event):       0 op/s

Transactions Received/Sent: 2 / 0
 Rate (overall):         0 tx/s    (peak: 0 tx/s)
      (per event):       0 tx/s

3 records processed as of Mon Aug 24 10:51:14 CST 2015 (rate 0/sec, delta 3)

*************************************************
```

Anybody know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others who may encounter this problem:

It turns out to be a bug...

I swithed from **Version 12.1.2.1.4 20470586 OGGCORE_12.1.2.1.0OGGBP_PLATFORMS_150303.1209** to **Version 11.2.1.0.1 OGGCORE_11.2.1.0.1_PLATFORMS_120423.0230**. Everything works fine now.